# Flutter firebase-auth integration testing signInWithCredential error: The caller does not have permission to execute the specified

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutterdriver, flutter-integration-test

I'm trying to run integration tests on my flutter app.
One of the flows I want to test is the Login flow. There is a firebase phone number authentication in the app.
When I'm trying to call signInWithCredential to sign in with the test phone number and test verification code, I'm getting an error:

```
I/flutter (24151): The following FirebaseException was thrown running a test:
I/flutter (24151): [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified
I/flutter (24151): operation.
```

It looks like the SHA1 fingerprint configured in the Firebase project doesn't match the flutter driver app. Maybe I'm wrong about it.
My question is how to run an integration test for an app with firebase-auth. And I'm right about SHA1 - how to set up a singing configuration for the flutter driver app?